# Python PhantomJS & Beautifulsoup Scraping Java - What's Missing Here?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

Scraping static pages works fine like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")


for results in soup.findAll("li", {"class" : "open"}):
    print(results.get_text())
```

But Javascript sites are causing me a problem.

So I'm using PhantomJS and the obvious thought at the start was "it's just not loaded when I'm trying to scrape".

So I stuck in a time.sleep (not ideal - I know I'll swap to a presence_of_element_locate) and a:

```
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png') # save a screenshot to disk
```

That screenshot shows the data I'm looking for has loaded. I'm able to scrape other bits of data off that page using the same code as above for the elements loaded without Java.

According to the screenshot the data is there on the page. And I use the same data as I do on .Net libs which read the same site fine.

```
for names in soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "the-name ng-name ng-big-scope"}):
        print(names)
```

I removed the .get_text() here just in case that was causing something to break. But either way this returns nothing. And I can't work out why.

I can use the exact same data in vb.net:

```
 For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
   If element.GetAttribute("className").Contains("the-name ng-name ng-big-scope") Then
                    print(element.innertext)
   End If
Next
```

I know I use a .contains in the .net example there but I've triple checked it's the right class name in this case.

So the syntax works on static data.
I have the class names etc... right because I can scrape it on .Net.
The data I'm looking for has loaded (according to the screenshot it takes).

I'm stumped. Would really appreciate anyone who can point out where I'm messing up here.

/Edit:

I ran a test on a different Javascript based site and it got the first result and a little of the second. When there was a dozen results there. Again .Net handled this without a problem.

So I'm considering the possibility that my syntax is fine and the problem is BF handling malformed code on the site. Going to try with an alternative or two and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out nothing wrong with the code.

Malformed HTML on the site was causing problems with lxml resulting in no results being read.